# SSIS - Script Issue creating a DateTime

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datetime, ssis

I'm using SSIS to upload data from a CSV file to a table from my database. I try to get 2 strings (one is for the date, the other is for the time) and concat them like this :

```
string datsDateTime = String.Concat(Row.DATE, " ", Row.HEURE);
```

Then, I try to parse it like this :

```
Row.DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(datsDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

But it does not work. When I try to test this script, I got this error :

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. Any idea about it?

**EDIT** : In my column "date" which is in my csv file, the date is a string which is like this : *20120101* (2012, 01 for the month and 01 for the day).

**UPDATE** : Ok I found the solution by doing this
`string datsDateTime = Row.DATE.Insert(6,"/").Insert(4, "/") + " " + Row.HEURE;` 
before pasing anything. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change the format to

```
Row.FinalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datsDateTime, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm", null);
```

Since your getting dates in `yyyymmdd` format 
Dates are stored not as `string`  but as `integers` .If you want to display the data in dd/mm/yyyy format then you can use ToString() method with a specific format like

```
YourDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

but since you are storing in your database then ,it will be stored as integers 
Check the Dateformat in your sql server

```
dbcc useroptions
```